# multiple environments in docker from one git repository

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Iam trying to deploy two main environments , development and production .

the problem im facing is that the docker volumes are mapped through the local drive , thus if I created 2 containers as the following architecture :

```
#docker-compose file
services
 nginx_main:
    build:./nginx_main
    volumes:
     - .:/var/www/html
 nginx_dev:
    build:./nginx_dev
    volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html
```

nginx_dev > Dockerfile is like this

```
From nginx:latest
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN git checkout dev
```

and nginx_main's is like this :

```
From nginx:latest
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN git checkout main
```

when I do `docker-compose up` it actually checks out the same branch at each container !

Comment: You are mounting both to the same host directory, so they overwrite each other.

Comment: I just tried to keep the dev directory mounted but the main is copied to the container .. it works fine but I doubt it is the best solution .. what do you think ?

Comment: Do not hard-code the environment in the Dockerfile. Use an environment variable to specify which environment to run.

Answer (score 0):

You know what the picture you want, but you have to partition volume.
As you `git checkout` on the `Dockerfile`, the code appears to have been inserted into the docker image. so, only the volume mounting needs to be modified.

```yaml
# docker-compose.yaml
services:
 nginx_main:
    build:./nginx_main
    volumes:
     - ./main:/var/www/html
 nginx_dev:
    build:./nginx_dev
    volumes:
    - ./dev:/var/www/html
```